# How many matrices satisfy this equality?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How many matrices $A\in\mathcal{M}_{3\times 3} (\mathbb{N})$ satisfy this equality?

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 \ \ 2 \ \ 4
\end{pmatrix}\cdot A=\begin{pmatrix}
3 \ \ 2 \ \ 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

I tried with examples and I found just one but I want to know how to approach this exercise.The right answer is $3$

Comment: What are the entries of $A$? Integers, real numbers...?

Comment: natural numbers

Comment: I forgot about that.I edited my question

Comment: @Yanko the matrix is multiplied from the left with a row vector, which makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let $A=[x_{i,j}]$ Then we get

$$x_{1,1} +2 x_{2,1} +4 x_{3,1} = 3$$

$$ x_{1,2} + 2x_{2,2} + 4 x_{3,2} = 2 $$

$$x_{1,3} + 2 x_{2,3} + 4 x_{3,3} = 1$$

We shall count the number of solutions for each equation.

**First equation has 2 solutions:**
Since $4>3$ we have that $x_{3,1}=0$. Similarly $x_{2,1}<2$. If $x_{2,1}=1$ then $x_{1,1}=1$ and if $x_{2,1}=0$ then $x_{1,1}=3$. Therefore there are two solutions for the first equation.

**Second equation has 2 solutions:**
As before, $x_{3,2}=0$. Also $x_{2,2}$ is at most $1$, hence if $x_{2,2}=1$ then $x_{1,2}=0$ and if not then $x_{2,2}=0$ and $x_{1,2}=1$.

**Third equation has 1 solution:**
$4,2>1$ so $x_{2,3},x_{3,3}=0$ and so the only solution is $x_{1,3}=1$.

Therefore there is a total of $4$ solutions for all of the equations.

$$A_1 =\begin{bmatrix} 3 & 0 &1  \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}, A_2=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 &1  \\ 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$
$$A_3 =\begin{bmatrix} 3 & 2 &1  \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}, A_4=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 &1  \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: The OP forgot to mention that their definition of $\mathbb{N}$ includes $0$ because otherwise there are zero solutions.

Comment: Thank for your answer.If $x_{2,1}=1$ then $x_{1,1}=1$, right? Because otherwise the result will be 4

Comment: @DaniVaja Correct. Thank you